# Django: Submitting two forms on one page and using data from first form in second form

Tags: python, html, django, forms, python-requests-html

so currently I have a web page where the user can select stats they want and then generate a march madness bracket. If they decide they like the bracket they can name it and save it. I want to save the bracket as well as the stats chosen. My issue is that I have two forms on one page, so when the user presses the save button, the stats variables are all empty since their values were assigned in the request for the other form. Basically the second form clears all data from the first form, but I want to use data from the first form in the second form. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<form method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}


<label for="stat1">Most Important Stat:</label>
<select name="stat1" id="stat1">
  <option value="Stat 1">Stat 1</option>
  <option value="Stat 2">Stat 2</option>
  <option value="Stat 3">Stat 3</option>
  <option value="Stat 4">Stat 4</option>
  <option value="Stat 5">stat 5</option>
</select>

<label for="stat2">Second Most Important Stat:</label>
<select name="stat2" id="stat2">
   <option value="Stat 1">Stat 1</option>
   <option value="Stat 2">Stat 2</option>
   <option value="Stat 3">Stat 3</option>
   <option value="Stat 4">Stat 4</option>
   <option value="Stat 5">stat 5</option>
</select>

<label for="stat3">Third Most Important Stat:</label>
<select name="stat3" id="stat3">
   <option value="Stat 1">Stat 1</option>
   <option value="Stat 2">Stat 2</option>
   <option value="Stat 3">Stat 3</option>
   <option value="Stat 4">Stat 4</option>
   <option value="Stat 5">stat 5</option>
</select>

 <label for="stat4">Fourth Most Important Stat:</label>
 <select name="stat4" id="stat4">
   <option value="Stat 1">Stat 1</option>
   <option value="Stat 2">Stat 2</option>
   <option value="Stat 3">Stat 3</option>
   <option value="Stat 4">Stat 4</option>
   <option value="Stat 5">stat 5</option>
 </select>

 <label for="stat5">Fifth Most Important Stat:</label>
 <select name="stat5" id="stat5">
    <option value="Stat 1">Stat 1</option>
    <option value="Stat 2">Stat 2</option>
    <option value="Stat 3">Stat 3</option>
    <option value="Stat 4">Stat 4</option>
    <option value="Stat 5">stat 5</option>
 </select>

 <button onclick="createBracket(request)" >Submit</button>
 </form>

 <form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="txt_field">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" required>
    <label>Bracket Name</label>
  </div>

  <input type="Submit" value="Save Bracket">
 </form>
```

views.py:

```
def createBracket(request, user_id):
   user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)


   # choosing the stats
   if request.method == 'GET' and 'stat1' in request.GET:
      stat1 = request.GET.get('stat1')
      stat2 = request.GET.get('stat2')
      stat3 = request.GET.get('stat3')
      stat4 = request.GET.get('stat4')
      stat5 = request.GET.get('stat5')

      ordered_stats = [stat1, stat2, stat3, stat4, stat5]
      # call some function and pass in stats

      # function returns a list of teams which is my "bracket"
      bracket = ["Virginia-Tech", "Colgate", "Arkansas", "Florida", "Drexel", "Illinois", "Utah St", "Texas Tech"]
      context = {'user': user, 'user_id': user_id, 'bracket': bracket}
   else:
      context = {'user': user, 'user_id': user_id, 'bracket': bracket}

   print(stat1)
   # naming and saving the bracket
   if request.method == 'POST' and 'name' in request.POST:
       save_form = SaveForm(request.POST)
       print("saved the form")
       if save_form.is_valid():
  
           database = Bracket.objects.create(
               bracket_name=save_form.cleaned_data['name'],
               user=user,
               bracket=bracket,
               stat1=stat1, # this won't work bc stat1 isn't assigned
               stat2=stat2,
               stat3=stat3,
               stat4=stat4,
               stat5=stat5,
           )
           database.save()
           context = {'user': user, 'user_id': user_id, 'bracket': bracket,
                       'save_form': save_form}

    else:
       save_form = SaveForm()
       context = {'user': user, 'user_id': user_id, 'bracket': bracket, 'save_form': save_form}

    return render(request, 'project/createBracket.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

So when createBracket gets called without anything, you're showing a totally empty form. The user fills in her stats, presses  submit on the top form, gets the same page back again showing the stats she just entered, plus your bracket. She chooses the bracket, and a name for it and then submits the bottom form? Why do you need the first form submitted to show her the exact values that she just entered? Can you not just display one empty form with your bracket populated and do the whole thing in one form? I mean I suppose you could use JavaScript to prevent default on the bottom form and get your top form values before posting, which would solve your problem, but I'm not quite understanding the need for two submits. You're not doing anything with the data on the first submit.

Edit: actually on the GET submit what are you doing with the stats? You're not putting them back into the context and you're not using them as initial form field values, so they're just lost?

Comment: We are using the stats selected to do some analysis and generate a bracket of teams. I don't have that part of the code yet but basically once the state are chosen they will be used to make a function call within the view which will return a list of teams to fill in the bracket with. I want the user to be able to generate a bracket and then decide whether to save it or not. But when creating a new database entry for the bracket I want the stats and list of teams to be saved there, which currently won't happen because they are cleared when the second form is submitted.

Comment: @Sophia Ok. Well you could take your stats on the GET submit, and use them as initial values to hidden fields in your second form. It's a bit hacky, but it would work. You will probably want to prevent form submission on your bottom form without those present though. Either that or re-render your form after the second submit passing back the top form values as initial values and using JavaScript to get them on submit of the bottom form. Or using two views, with the stats captured in the url, or passing them to the second view as ?stat1=1&stat2=2 etc. Or storing them in a cookie.